# bash-for each value in JSON file execute command

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

I have json file (1.json), i can iterate through it to find project,parent keys and custom fields

```
jq -r '.issues[] | .key' 1.json
jq -r '.issues[] | .fields.project.key' 1.json
jq -r '.issues[] | .fields.customfield_10107.id' 1.json
```

Output:

```
TECH-540
TECH-531
TECH-627
TECH-538
TECH-577
TECH-572
TECH-520
TECH-565
TECH-567
TECH
TECH
TECH
TECH
TECH
TECH
TECH
TECH
TECH
10400
10400
10400
10400
10400
10400
10400
10400
10400
```

I want to store TECH-XXX to project=`jq -r '.issues[] | .key' 1.json`
TECH to parent=`jq -r '.issues[] | .fields.project.key' 1.json`
10400 to custom_field=`jq -r '.issues[] | .fields.customfield_10107.id' 1.json`
variable
for each value found in 1.json file do for loop following code (in this case run curl 9 times):

```
curl -D- -u user:pass -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"$project\"},\"parent\":{\"key\":\"$parent\"},\"summary\":\"Test ChargenNr\",\"description\":\"some description\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Sub-task\"},\"customfield_10107\":{\"id\":\"$custom_field\"}}}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://jira.company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using nested loop

```
for project in `cat 1.json  | jq -r .issues[].key`; do

  for parent in `cat 1.json  | jq -r .issues[].fields.project.key`; do
     for custom_field in `cat 1.json  | jq -r .issues[].fields.customfield_10107.id`; do

      echo $i>/tmp/ja.txt

done
  done
    echo $project $parent  $custom_field
    curl -D- -u user:pass -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"$project\"},\"parent\":{\"key\":\"$parent\"},\"    summary\":\"Test ChargenNr\",\"description\":\"some description\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Sub-task\"},\"customfield_10107\":{\"id\":\"$custom_field\"}}}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://jira.company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/
    done
```